# mySQL to Core Data on XCode

Tags: mysql, ios, xcode, core-data

For my app i have an online mySQL (with InnoDB) Database, but it's a bit slow and user experience is not the best. I need data into my app, ready to use.
To to this i want to create a "cache" of my dataBase downloaded on the device. So i have to use Core Data. But how can i download all data and put it with the correct structure in the Core Data db? Are there other way to have an "offline cache", or i have to manually recreate the structure and populate the Core Data with the element downloaded from my DB?
Thanks!

Comment: You could also have a look at SQLite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're already working directly with MySQL, you should probably use SQLite directly instead of switching to Core Data. Although SQLite isn't exactly the same as MySQL, it's a lot closer to it than Core Data is. You're still speaking SQL, still using tables directly in a relational database, etc. Unless you have some compelling other reason to do so, I wouldn't recommend switching to Core Data in this case.