# MySQL and Core Data in iOS

Tags: mysql, ios, core-data

I want to retrieve data from remote MySQL database and store the data in my iOS app (creating "local" database, so the information can still be accessed even though there is no connection). After doing some research, Apple's Core Data API seems to be the answer. However, it's using SQLite.

Can I use Core data with MySQL?  If the answer is no, is there any way to develop "local" database other than Core Data? I tried looking for the answer, but no luck. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19275414/mysql-to-core-data-on-xcode) is the closest one that I can get, but I don't really understand the answer. I am new at iOS development, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use Core Data with MySQL if you like, but you need to write the persistent store functionality yourself, which is a fairly advanced undertaking.  It doesn't seem to have any benefits though.  I think it would be better to retrieve the data from the MySQL server, and then store it locally in Sqlite.  MySQL requires a separate server so obviously it cannot be run locally on iOS anyway.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is really concise and clear. I think I will go with your solution: retrieve data from MySQL server, and store it locally. One follow up question though: by "store it locally in Sqlite" you mean by using Core Data right?

Comment: Yes, via Core Data.  It is the easiest way.

Comment: And is it possible to control the frequencies of pulling data from the web server (let say the data rarely change)?

Comment: That's another question entirely, so why not ask it?

Comment: Posted, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19946120/controlling-frequency-of-data-retrieving-from-remote-server-ios

Answer (score 1):

You cant use coredata with MySQL. Because CoreData is a local database inside the mobile and MySQL is WebServer database. So we cant combine them. Why you dont like CoreData? It is the most powerful and simple database for the mobile apps. I think CoreData suits for your purpose. If your data is something lightweight. Then you can use

1. Plist

   http://hayageek.com/plist-tutorial/

   http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/05/30/property-list-tutorial-using-plist-to-store-user-data/
2. NSCoder

   http://www.raywenderlich.com/1914/nscoding-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-save-your-app-data

Comment: I have no opinion towards Core Data since I have never used it, but I have a MySQL webserver db, and I thought I cannot fetch data and store it using CoreData earlier (I misunderstood Core Data's purpose as local database).

Answer (score 0):

CoreData is the way to go. CoreData is build under SQLLite but it is a relational data base --> Object Oriented mapping which makes it really convenient.

There's a graphic editor which will allow you to define your CoreData model the way you require it.